# Stuck in Contract or something similar

Tags: ethereum-wallet-dapp, contract-debugging

Hey guys i almost sent ethereum to a scam address luckily it got rejected cause i didnt use enough gas. this is the ethersacan transaction https://etherscan.io/tx/0xd766aa25906b7ea2db40bbe5ef3559bad3e7ec355c9649f042c57d64bfa26719
How can i get the ethereum back now? I already tried to send a different transaction to overwrite it but its still not back.....

Please help...

Answer (score 0):

[Transaction](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xd766aa25906b7ea2db40bbe5ef3559bad3e7ec355c9649f042c57d64bfa26719) status is **success**. If it was a scam, then you successfully sent 0.3 Ether to him. Once the tx is included in the block and block is mined you cannot revert it and there is no one who can help you, I am sorry.

Be careful when sending real Ether to someone you don't know.

### Always verify:

- You are on the trusted website
- This is a [legit token address](https://etherscan.io/tokens)
- You know a person who sent the address to you

Comment: fml ty though... at least i know for sure now....

Answer (score -1):

[image]It says rejected in meta mask though with exlamatin mark

Comment: Added an image now its the second from the bottom